# Custom button in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having problem with creating a custom button in twitter bootsrap 3.

I need to do button like that (with triangle in right bottom corner).
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZAv0.jpg

I know that one way to resolve that problem is to use background of this button and add text. But is there a custom button generator to do button like that ?

Best regards

Comment: How abt using the bg-image for button & positioning it to bottom center with a bg-color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot let Bootstrap generate this button for you, but you can define it yourself in your CSS.

Here's a cool solution using CSS only:

```
<a href="#">Button!</a>


a{
    background:#b6174d;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial;
    position:relative
}

a:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    border-width: 0px 0px 13px 13px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #fff transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
}

a:hover{
   background: #e83370;
}
```

Or check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9tPcZ/1/

Answer (score 1):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/samithaHewawasam/mVJ9j/)

```
<div style="background: gray; height: 100px; width: 200px; position: relative;">
    <div style="height: 1px; width: 1px; border-top: solid gray 20px; border-right: solid white 20px; position: absolute; bottom: -1px; right: 0;"></div>
</div>
```

Or Use this [Jquery Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/)

Comment: Also very cool solution :) I will remember that jquery plugin :)

Answer (score 0):

Create using CSS :after pseudo class

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/cqT4m/

**HTML**

```
<a class="button" href="#">
    My big Button
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.button {
    background:#FF0000;
    padding:10px 30px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.button:after {
    content:"";
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 0 12px 12px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #FFF transparent;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: I was definitely first! >:D

Comment: @Milanzor Just saw your answer after posting mine. :-)